# Can you aggregate data in a waterfall chart with Plotly?

Tags: plotly, flexdashboard, crosstalk

I am creating an R flexdashboard with a waterfall chart that show sales over time. There is a filter_select (crosstalk) that allows you to select one group at a time.  I'd like to enable multi-select and have the amount won aggregate across selections rather than showing two separate series on the chart. Does anyone know if this is possible?

````
waterfall_sd <- SharedData$new(won.loss.waterfall.data,group="shared data 2")
filter_select("sectorWF.filter","Select Segment", waterfall_sd, ~Segment, multiple = TRUE)

```

Row 
-------------------------------------

### Year to Date Summary {data-height=550}

```{r echo = FALSE}

plot_ly(waterfall_sd, type = "waterfall") %>%
                             add_trace(measure = ~Amount.Won, x = ~Award.Quarter, name = "Wins", textposition = "outside", y= ~Amount.Won, text =~paste("$",round(Amount.Won/1000000,1),"M; ",Num.Won," Opps",sep=""),decreasing = list(marker = list(color = '#93d500', line = list(color = '#93d500', width = 2))), increasing = list(marker = list(color = '#93d500', line = list(color = '#93d500', width = 3))),totals = list(marker = list(color = '#93d500', line = list(color = '#93d500', width = 3))),connector = list(line = list(color= '#93d500'))) %>% 
    add_trace(measure = ~Amount.Lost, x = ~Award.Quarter, name = "Losses", textposition = "outside", y= ~Amount.Lost, text =~paste("$",round(Amount.Lost/1000000,1),"M; ",Num.Lost," Opps", sep=""),decreasing = list(marker = list(color =  '#f37620', line = list(color =  '#f37620', width = 2))), increasing = list(marker = list(color =  '#f37620', line = list(color =  '#f37620', width = 3))),totals = list(marker = list(color =  '#f37620', line = list(color =  '#f37620', width = 3))),connector = list(line = list(color=  '#f37620'))) %>%
  layout(title = "2020 Wins and Losses",
        xaxis = list(title = "Quarter"),
        yaxis = list(title = ""),
        autosize = FALSE,
        showlegend = TRUE,width = 1625, height = 450)
````